# How to exclude stashes while querying refs?

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to query for commits:

```
repo.Commits.QueryBy(new LibGit2Sharp.Filter { Since = repo.Refs }).Take(100)
```

This is otherwise ok, but it also returns stashes. How can I exclude stashes? I know that when I'm looping through the results I could just ignore them I guess, but then I wouldn't have 100 of them as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Since` and `Until` properties of the `Filter` type are quite tolerant regarding what they can be valued with.

According to the documentation they

> Can either be a **string** containing the sha or reference canonical name to use, 
>   a **Branch**, a **Reference**, a **Commit**, a **Tag**,
>   a **TagAnnotation**, an **ObjectId** or even a mixed collection of all of the above.

Basically, `Since = repo.Refs` means *"I want to revwalk from **every** reference of the repository when enumerating the pointed at commits"*.

Similarly to `git log --all` this will indeed consider the *branches*, the *tags*, the *stash*, the *notes*, ...

If you're willing to reduce the scope of the references, you'll have to select what `Since` will be valued with.

- `Since = repo.Branches.Where(b => !b.IsRemote)`
- `Since = new object[] { repo.Branches["br2"], "refs/heads/master", new ObjectId("e90810b") }`

For instance, in order to only consider branches and tags, you'd use

`Since = new object[]{ repo.Branches, repo.Tags }`

Comment: Do you think there's any way to take those commits into account that are not referenced by any branch or the HEAD ref? Basically, loop through EVERY commit in the order of date/creation, no matter if it's referenced or not.

Comment: This would require to leverage the reflog and/or git fschk. Those features are not available yet.