# What is the LibGit2Sharp equivalent of git log path?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

How do I get a list of commits which contain a particular file, ie the equivalent of `git log path` for `LibGit2Sharp`.

Has it not been implemented or is there a way that I'm missing?

Comment: There's a **[feature request](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/89)** in the LibGit2Sharp issue tracker specifically dealing with this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was working on getting the same functionality into my application with LibGit2Sharp.

I wrote the code below which will list all of the commits that contain the file. The GitCommit class isn't included, but it is just a collection of properties.

My intention was to have the code only list commits where the file had changed, similar to a SVN log, but I haven't written that part yet.

*Please note that the code hasn't been optimized, it was merely my initial attempt, but I hope it will be useful.*

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads the history for a file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath">Path to file</param>
/// <returns>List of version history</returns>
public List<IVersionHistory> LoadHistory(string filePath)
{
    LibGit2Sharp.Repository repo = new Repository(this.pathToRepo);

    string path = filePath.Replace(this.pathToRepo.Replace(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + ".git", string.Empty), string.Empty).Substring(1);
    List<IVersionHistory> list = new List<IVersionHistory>();

    foreach (Commit commit in repo.Head.Commits)
    {
        if (this.TreeContainsFile(commit.Tree, path) && list.Count(x => x.Date == commit.Author.When) == 0)
        {
            list.Add(new GitCommit() { Author = commit.Author.Name, Date = commit.Author.When, Message = commit.MessageShort} as IVersionHistory);
        }
    }

    return list;
}

/// <summary>
/// Checks a GIT tree to see if a file exists
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tree">The GIT tree</param>
/// <param name="filename">The file name</param>
/// <returns>true if file exists</returns>
private bool TreeContainsFile(Tree tree, string filename)
{
    if (tree.Any(x => x.Path == filename))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Tree branch in tree.Where(x => x.Type == GitObjectType.Tree).Select(x => x.Target as Tree))
        {
            if (this.TreeContainsFile(branch, filename))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is an `IVersionHistory`?

Comment: @toofarsideways my application works with SVN and Git repos, so I have a interface for file version history logs.

Comment: I'd suggest you to rather use diff based approach which should be faster. You can peek at a proposal leveraging this approach **[here](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/89#issuecomment-6983251)**

Comment: I've noticed that earlier, however, I'm not sure where `repo.History` which appears in `libgit2sharp/Follow test/Program.cs` appears in... I suppose I'd better pull it down and grep it then, thanks!

Comment: @nulltoken Right, found it and trying it out, unfortunately it doesn't seem to generate the commit list for the file.

Comment: A bug? Ah. Maybe could you add a comment to the code in order to ping the author?

Comment: @nulltoken That's the odd thing, he has written a test case, that I suspect is fully functioning, I'll have a crack tracing this thing to see if I can isolate it...

Comment: @nulltoken Ok, I've figured out my error, I'm running it against an older commit, however the new version uses a version of `Diff.Compare` that doesn't exist on the NuGet 0.95 package version. Cue fiddling with the compiled version and trying to work out how to fix the `Proxy.cs` file complaining about an `EntryPointNotFoundException` as apparently `git_index_get_bypath` isn't implemented in the git.dll that ships with that version. (I'm using `vNext 1f3757bd`)

Comment: The dll has to to match the managed code. I'd suggest starting from the vNext branch. Also, maybe should we take this discussion out of SO? :-)

Answer (score 6):

Each time when tree/blob has been changed it gets new id hash.
All you need is to compare with parent commit tree/blob item hash:

```
var commits = repository.Commits
   .Where(c => c.Parents.Count() == 1 && c.Tree["file"] != null &&
      (c.Parents.FirstOrDefault().Tree["file"] == null ||
         c.Tree["file"].Target.Id !=
         c.Parents.FirstOrDefault().Tree["file"].Target.Id));
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. This is the best mechanism I have come across.

Answer (score 5):

[LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) comes from the C library [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/)... which didn't include `git log` in the first place ;)

Yet, LibGit2Sharp has its own `git log` function:
Its [page on `git log`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-log) involves [**Filters**](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Filter.cs), but a Filter doesn't seem to filter by path (as detailed in "[How to exclude stashes while querying refs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10840451/6309)").
So it doesn't seem to be implemented at the moment.

Comment: The C library, I think you mean.

Comment: Is there any way to manually walk the structure? Or would I have to get a list of the commits and then exclude the ones that do not touch the file I'm interested in?

Comment: @toofarsideways as dmck's answer illustrates, you would have to get the commits and filter yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to dmck's answer but more up to date

```
private bool TreeContainsFile(Tree tree, string filePath)
{
    //filePath is the relative path of your file to the root directory
    if (tree.Any(x => x.Path == filePath))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return tree.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof (TreeEntry))
        .Select(x => x.Target)
        .OfType<Tree>()
        .Any(branch => TreeContainsFile(branch, filePath));
}
```